# Finding the absolute value of the roots of a polynomial

Tags: equation-solving, polynomials

So I am trying to find the absolute value of the roots of a polynomial in Mathematica. I am quite new to this software and I am having a hard time how to figure out the absolute value of the roots of a polynomial. Here's what I have done.

- I defined a polynomial say `P[degree_,z_]:= (*something*)`
- Now I use: `Solve[P[5,z]==0]`
  This gives me the exact roots of the polynomial, but if I use `Abs[Solve[P[5,z]==0]]`, this doesn't return the absolute values of the roots.
  Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps `z /. Solve[p[z] == 0, z] // Abs // N`

Answer (score 1):

Since `Solve[P[degree,z]]` returns a set of rules, so we need to modify it a little.

Let us define `data= Solve[P[degree,z]==0,z]` , then use `Table[z/.data[[i]],{i,1,degree}]` this table gives us the value of the roots corresponding to the $i$th position. Now this is a number and we can apply mathematical operations here.

Using `Table[Abs[z/.data[[i]]],{i,1,degree}]` will return the absolute values of the roots.

**Extra observation:** If the polynomial have very complicated roots and mathematica returns them in *not so simple form* we can use `NSolve` as long as we are only concerned about the absolute value of roots.

Comment: Or to leave solution (roots) as rules, `roots /. (z -> root_) :> (z -> Abs[root])`